What to do with CVEs and vulnerable CPUs?
Recently a vulnerability that targets Intel CPUs and Linux OSs was reported on.
CVE-2024-2201 (aka: Inspectre Gadget / Spectre v2.0) has me rather concerned.
Q: I would like to know the correct procedure in trying to protect my Ubuntu PCs as much as possible.
Traditionally I head straight to the motherboard manufacturer (ASUS) and download the latest BIOS update and patch quickly. Then hope that the great Linux coders come up with a kernel patch soon.
However, is that the right thing to do? I try to get those using the PC's I watch over to practice safe computing (delete suspicious emails/ don't download anything from places other than repos).
Also, ASUS gives up fairly quickly on its motherboard BIOS patches. I have intel CPUs (all ASUS motherboards) that are: 6th, 9th, 11th (laptop) & 13th gen & only the last one gets updates bios still.
Q: are there other sources of bios/firmware patches available? intel directly?
Does intel work with the linux coders directly to fix this?

I would probably go to https://ubuntu.com/security/cves and enter the CVE so you go the appropriate page (ie. https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2024-2201) which lets you find your release and see the current status... For most CVEs you'll find you're not impacted OR have a package version to ensure you have installed to know you have the fix..    if it's a rather recent CVE you have a page to check back on.

According to Intel though, all my CPUs are vulnerable.
While I can wait on the linux coders for their side of it, are bios updates the only solution I have to apply as well?
